# Font used by BMW's model numbers

Tags: font-identification

I would like to know exact or similar font that is used for "316i", "318is", "325" or similar, in the following pictures of 1980s and 1990s e30 BMWs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried various web searches, including searching BMW enthusiast forums, but no luck so far.

Comment: Probably this is the lettering process, not real font. http://i.stack.imgur.com/vnHG4.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure but I would guess [Microgramma Extended Bold](http://www.identifont.com/show?645) or [Eurostile Extended Medium](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/eurostile/ext-med/glyphs.html). It's hard to determine just from a few numbers and letters as specimen but it seems like the stresses are the same on Eurostile Extended Medium.

The cultural context and time period also make sense, as both these typefaces were designed by Aldo Novarese and were popular professional types in Europe from the mid '60's on.

BMW may have had a modified cut with different stresses on the vertical strokes for the beveled model numbers but most wouldn't notice the difference between that and Eurostile or Microgramma.

If nothing else you could get some more specimens and modify Eurostile or Microgramma to fit if you just have a little display copy or use them as a starting point on [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/index.html).

Comment: Your first link does not work. Just though I'd let you know.

Answer (score 3):

I think are original style font created for BMW, Im a Diecast 1/18 collector, and some of my models lost those numbers and logos. I use the pictures in google and re create the fonts of this numbers styles.. 98.9% identical.  is easy if you work in [image: Illustrator].  Write to me if you need those logos.

Comment: Luis, How do I write to you for the badge file? Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I've been told and it looks correct based, again, on what few letters we have to go from that it is [Helvetica](http://www.identifont.com/find?font=helvetica)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Who told you? Is there an link on an bmw homepage about the used font?

Comment: It’s very, very obviously not Helvetica.

Comment: wow. just... wow.